# Setting visibility for dynamically created RelativeLayouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating multiple relative layouts dynamically and adding them to my layout

```
            RelativeLayout stepsBackgroundRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lprams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            lprams.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
            stepsBackgroundRelativeLayout.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
            stepsBackgroundRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(lprams);
            stepsBackgroundRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.step_background);
            stepsBackgroundRelativeLayout.setId(100 + i);
```

Now I want to make invisible 103 and 104 no relativelayout.

**What I had tried -**

```
                    stepsBackgroundRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But it make every layouts go invisible.

**What I am trying to do-**

I am having 10 - 12 relative layout I am creating it dynamically each and every relative layout having a button when user going to click one button of a relative layout it should visible another relative layout.By default other relative layout should be invisible except the first one.

Comment: 103 and 104 ? are they some top secret codes?

Comment: Look at this line stepsBackgroundRelativeLayout.setId(100 + i);
I am looping that i and adding it with 100 to make a RelativeLayout id

Comment: its still a big mistery what you want to do...

Comment: stepsBackgroundRelativeLayout int he code you have tried which id has?

why don't store the relativeLayouts in an array, and choose which you what to be invisible.

Comment: @pskink I am having 10 - 12 relative layout I am creating it dynamically each and every relative layout having a button when user going to click one button of a relative layout it should visible another relative layout.By default other relative layout should be invisible except the first one.